# Finding The Top 3 Values In Specific Column

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I have the following problem which I am struggling to solve.

See the image below - the table shows how many times a firm had a specific problem.

[Picture of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5blt.png)

I would like to create a formula that gives me the the **top 3 problems** of the **5 companies with the most problems in total** (which in this case would be Company 4,3,6,7 and 1)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean for each of the top 5 companies, what are their top 3 problems (per company), or across all the top 5 companies, what are the 3 biggest problems?

Comment: Hi Alex, I mean the former -> per company

Answer (score 0):

As per your image, try this formula in cell `B14`:

```
=IF(B$12>=LARGE($B$12:$H$12,5),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(LARGE(B$2:B$11,1),B$2:B$11,0)+1,1)),"")
```

Now drag the formula across to column H and down to row 16.